# invalid category error in response for microsoft custom translator api

Tags: microsoft-translator

Apparently, according to MS Azure support, I need to post a question here rather than being able to ask somewhere at MS, so here goes....

I have built a custom translation model in Custom Translation, and I'm sending the displayed 'category' id in my string inside this function in JS:

[screenshot showing category id](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FPQav.png)

```
function translateText() {

  var myText = 'こんにちわ。'　　//for example ;)
  var fromLan = 'ja'
  var toLan = 'en'
  var categoryId = 'c02fd3c3-d9cc-4943-b838-88aa9ba2fe75-FINANCE'
  var sp = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
  var token = sp.getProperty('ms_token');
  var url = 'https://api.microsofttranslator.com/v2/Http.svc/Translate';

  var hd = {
'Authorization': 'Bearer '+token
  };

  url += '?from=' + fromLan + '&to=' + toLan + '&category=' + categoryId + '&text=';
  url += encodeURIComponent(myText);

  var xml = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {
'method': 'get',
'headers': hd
  });
  xml = xml.getContentText();
  xml = xml.match(/^<string\s.*>(.*)<\/string>$/);
  return(xml[1]);
}
```

(This is in google sheets script. I was trying to put it in a custom function to use in the spreadsheet, but I've simplified it here to explain the problem)

But I get this error back in the response:

Message: Invalid category

[full response here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kjm5b.png)

Sorry, I'm not a coder by profession, so I've probably done something dumb, but can anyone please point out what it is?

You're awesome in advance!  Thanks

So I modified now to call V3, and instead of passing a token I can send the subscription key (according to the api docs), so my code is now:

```
function get_translate() {

  var myKey = 'mykeygoeshere';
  var myCategory = 'c02fd3c3-d9cc-4943-b838-88aa9ba2fe75-FINANCE';
  var myText = 'こんにちわ。';
  var toLanguage = "en";

  var url = 'https://api.cognitive.microsofttranslator.com/';
  url += 'translate?api-version=3.0'; 
  url += '&to=' + toLanguage + '&category=' + myCategory ;  

  var params = {
    'method': 'POST',
    'headers': {
        'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': myKey,
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },

    'body': {
        'text': myText
    }
  };

  var output = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params);

  Logger.log(output);

}
```

but the error log reports:

```
 {"error":{"code":400000,"message":"One of the request inputs is not valid."}}
```

can anyone please help?

latest error after adding the JSON.Stringify() - please see screenshot [[here]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8IIO1.png)[4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IKa9w.png)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are calling the V2 API.  You should be calling the V3 API for Custom Translator models. We have many examples of V3 API calls at https://github.com/microsofttranslator that should help you get started.

Please reach out if you need any additional assistance.

Comment: Thanks, so I changed the url to:    https://api.cognitive.microsofttranslator.com/translate?api-version=3.0 , but then the error becomes:  returned code 405. Truncated server response: {"code":405000,"message":"The request method is not supported for the requested resource."}.    If I change my request to 'post' I get a different error of:    returned code 401. Truncated server response: {"error":{"code":401000,"message":"The request is not authorized because credentials are missing or invalid."}}

Comment: can anyone help with this please?

Comment: You were almost there.  You need to put the body in the full JSON format.  Replace body with this

'body': JSON.stringify([{
        'text': myText
    }])

Comment: Thanks again @ScottG. But unfortunately still see the same error. I added a screenshot to my original post

Comment: please try to add region header 'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Region':<your api region>

Comment: The @Chirag "region" solution worked for me. Thank you !!